# React Native horrible performance after react hooks + arrow function

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, hybrid-mobile-app, arrow-functions

I think the title says pretty much all, but i'll give u a resume anyways.

This is the second project i've worked on react native, but this time i decided to implement new stuff, like react native hooks and arrow functions (which i didn't implement before), so instead of rendering a screen with the typical

```
 export default class 'ScreenName' extends Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props);

   this.state = {'states here'}
  }

  render(){
   return(
    'code here'
   );
  }
}
```

i did it this way

```
const 'ScreenName' = () => {
 const [stateName, setName] = useState('');
 'other states here'

 return(
  'code here'
 );
}
```

the thing is, my app has become a pain to navigate, and no, this isn't a navigation issue, i disabled the animation transitions, and every screen is slow, even those with low quantity of images or lists, here is a example of one of my screens, probably the slowest so far.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StatusBar, RefreshControl, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import {Header, Overlay} from 'react-native-elements';
import {ListItem} from 'react-native-elements';
import Images from '../../Assets/values/images';
import Colors from '../../Assets/values/colors';
import DataManager from '../../../Util/CrossUtils/DataManager';
import VacationHistoryBusiness from '../../../Template/ViewModel/Vacation/VacationHistory/VacationHistoryBusiness';
import Constants from '../../Assets/values/styles/Vacation/VacationStyleConstants';
import ModalSuccessRequest from '../../Assets/Components/ModalSuccessRequest';
import styles from '../../Assets/values/styles/Vacation/VacationStyle';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

const VacationScreen = (props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    VacationHistoryBusiness.GetInstance().getListVacation;
    VacationHistoryBusiness.GetInstance().getLastObjectRequestVacation;
  })

  function _onRefresh() {}

  const [isVisible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const [isRefreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);
  const listItem = [{id: 0,titulo: '07/12/2020',subtitulo: '07/23/2020',estado: 'Etiqueta'},{id: 1,titulo: '02/12/2020',subtitulo: '02/14/2020',estado: 'Etiqueta'},{id: 2,titulo: '11/04/2020',subtitulo: '11/08/2020',estado: 'Etiqueta'},{id: 3,titulo: '08/07/2020',subtitulo: '08/12/2020',estado: 'Etiqueta'}];

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
      <Header
        backgroundImage={Images.header_nav}
        backgroundImageStyle={styles.HeaderImagen}
        rightComponent={
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Login')}>
            <Image source={Images.logout}/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        }
        centerComponent={{text: Constants.HeaderTitle, ellipsizeMode: 'clip', style: styles.HeaderVacaciones }}
        placement='left'/>
      <View style={styles.ContainerBackground}>
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        <ImageBackground style={styles.VacacionesBackground} source={Images.img_vacaciones}>
          <View style={styles.RightComponent}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setVisible(true)}>
            <View style={styles.CenterInside}>
              <Image style={styles.DiasVacacionesComponent} source={Images.dias_vacaciones}/>
              <Text style={styles.DiasDisponiblesTitulo}>12</Text>
              <Text style={styles.DiasDisponiblesSubtitulo}>{Constants.DiasDisponiblesSubtitulo}</Text>
              <Text/>
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
        <ScrollView>
        {
          //DataManager.ObjectLastRequestVacation !== null ?
          listItem.length === 0 ? null :
          <View style={styles.Left}>
            <Text style={styles.ProximasVacacionesTitulo}>{Constants.ProximasVacacionesTitulo}</Text>
          </View>
          //: null
        }
        {
          //DataManager.ObjectLastRequestVacation !== null ?
          listItem.length === 0 ?
          <View style={styles.SinSolicitudes}>
            <Text style={styles.SinSolicitudesText}>{Constants.SinVacacionesDisponibles}</Text>
          </View>
          //: null
          :
          listItem.slice(0,1).map(value => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('VacationsDetail')}>
              <ListItem
                topDivider={true}
                bottomDivider={true}
                containerStyle={styles.ContainerLista}
                titleStyle={styles.TituloLista}
                subtitleStyle={styles.SubtituloLista}
                key={value.id}
                leftIcon={<Image resizeMode={'contain'} style={styles.LeftIcon} source={Images.vacaciones_ico}/>} 
                rightIcon={<Image resizeMode={'contain'} width={30} source={Images.chevron_right}/>} 
                title={`Desde ${dayjs(value.titulo).format('DD/MM')} hasta ${dayjs(value.subtitulo).format('DD/MM')}`}
                subtitle={
                  <View style={styles.BadgeEstado}>
                    <Text style={styles.SubtituloLista}>{value.estado}</Text>
                  </View>
                }/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))
        }
        {
          listItem.length === 0 ? null :
          <View style={styles.Left}>
            <Text style={styles.ProximasVacacionesTitulo}>{Constants.VacacionesAnterioresTitulo}</Text>
          </View>
        }
        {
          listItem.length === 0 ? null : 
          listItem.slice(1).map(value => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('VacationsDetail', {'Historico': true})}>
              <ListItem
                topDivider={true}
                bottomDivider={true}
                containerStyle={styles.ContainerLista}
                titleStyle={styles.TituloLista}
                subtitleStyle={styles.SubtituloLista}
                key={value.id}
                leftIcon={<Image resizeMode={'contain'} style={styles.LeftIcon} source={Images.vacaciones_ico}/>}
                rightIcon={<Image resizeMode={'contain'} width={30} source={Images.chevron_right}/>} 
                title={`Desde ${dayjs(value.titulo).format('DD/MM')} hasta ${dayjs(value.subtitulo).format('DD/MM')}`}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))
        }
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.BottomPush}/>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.ButtonSolicitarVacaciones} onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('VacationsRequest')}>
            <Text style={styles.TextSolicitarVacaciones}>{Constants.SolicitarVacaciones}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Overlay
          onBackdropPress={() => setVisible(false)}
          isVisible={isVisible}
          windowBackgroundColor={Colors.background_white}
          borderRadius={1}
          width='auto'
          height='auto'>
          <ModalSuccessRequest estado={isVisible} desde={dayjs('07/12/2020').format('DD/MM/YYYY')} hasta={dayjs('07/23/2020').format('DD/MM/YYYY')}/>
        </Overlay>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

export default VacationScreen;
```

Comment: The `useEffect` contained into `VacationScreen` component as no dependencies. This means that code will be executed and reallocated on every re-render.

Comment: i'll check this right away, i think i did it on every screen, thanks in advance

Comment: Ok let me know! One of my interns made this mistake into a custom hook and it was very slow to change states, maybe this could be the problem..

Comment: Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component... i get this error whenever i move the useEffect ouside VacationScreen, and it happens on every screen i got that function

Comment: I also noticed that whenever i move back and forth (from one screen to another), is like every image and component from VacationScreen is re rendering in real time, while in my first react native app this doesn't happen, and both are running on react navigation 4

Comment: The place for `useEffect` is good, but if that thing should be executed only after the first render, you should add an empty array of dependencies like `useEffect(() => { // your code }, [])` and like this you try to replicate the `componentDidMount()` logic. Also, there is no saving data after the fetch: your `listItem` should be also a state!

Comment: it certainly did improved, but is strange that whenever i change screens, it looks like every image is loading once again, and this wasn't happening on my previous app

Comment: Can you provide a video (or gif) to this?

Comment: sure, give me a day since i'm finishing the app, and i'll probably implement the performance boost on the next sprint

Comment: i changed the const to a function hook and improved the rendering